# Android build version automation in Git

Tags: android, git, svn, version-control, gradle

I used to automate build version in Subversion using following Gradle script:

```
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.*

buildscript {
    dependencies {
         classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.2+'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
        classpath group: 'org.tmatesoft.svnkit', name: 'svnkit', version: '1.7.11'
    }
}

def getSvnRevision() { //getting SVN revision #
    ISVNOptions options = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultOptions(true);
    SVNClientManager clientManager = SVNClientManager.newInstance(options);
    SVNStatusClient statusClient = clientManager.getStatusClient();
    SVNStatus status = statusClient.doStatus(projectDir, false);
    SVNRevision revision = status.getRevision();
    return revision.getNumber();
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        versionName = "1.0." + getSvnRevision()
        versionCode = 1000000 + getSvnRevision()
    }
}
```

Essense of this script is to get from SVN repo current revision # and use it as version # to generated `AndroidManifest.xml`, like:

```
<!--
 Version number encoding: XXYYZZZ
    XX 2 digits - major version
    YY 2 digits - minor version
    ZZZ 3 digits - build (SVN revision)
    Example: 0123456 is version 1.23.456
-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.package"
    android:versionCode="1000650"
    android:versionName="1.0.650" >
```

It makes my life significantly easier, e.g. when I receive bug report I can easily locate revision with issue. It really matters especially in case when one has several testers/distribution points where different versions are uploaded.

**Now question:**

How can I make something similar with Git? In Git there's no single revision #, instead there's only hash of branch - but it's alphanumeric - Android permits usage only of integers as version code.

Comment: for example you can use tags ...

Comment: Please be specific...

Comment: please use google ... yesterday i search similar stuff and i did find it ...SO is not human search engine

Comment: `git rev-list --count HEAD`, or a variant thereof.

Comment: Well, I got it - thanx. How can I script it using Gradle?

Comment: https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-git seems to satisfy your needs, haven't tried it myself so cannot 100% vouch for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I've figured how to do it. Here's code:

```
def getGitRevision = { ->
    try {
        def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        exec {
            standardOutput = stdout
            commandLine 'git', 'rev-list', '--first-parent', '--count', 'master'
        }
        println("Building revision #"+stdout)
        return asInteger(stdout.toString("ASCII").trim())
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
}

android {
    /*
    Version number encoding: XXYYZZZB
    XX 2 digits - major version
    YY 2 digits - minor version
    ZZZ 3 digits - build (VCS revision)
    B 1 digit - build variation/patch
    Example: 01234561 is version 1.23.456a
    */

    def char[] patches='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz'.toCharArray()
    def majorVersion=1
    def minorVersion=3
    def revision=getGitRevision()
    def patch=0
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.package"
        versionName = majorVersion + '.' + minorVersion + '.' + revision + patches[patch]
        versionCode = 10000000*majorVersion+10000*minorVersion + 10*revision+patch
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a shell script to generate the version, and inject it as environment variables:

---

```
# the build command (bash) in CI server

# versionCode: number of commits that are reachable from here
# *supposedly* monotonically increasing for each release build
export ANDROID_VERSION_CODE="$(git rev-list HEAD --count)"
# versionName: first 8 chars in commit SHA1
export ANDROID_VERSION_NAME="${GIT_COMMIT:0:8}"
```

---

```
// build.gradle

// read env variable as string or integer
def env = { System.getenv it }
def envInt = { Integer.parseInt(env(it)) }

android {
    defaultConfig {
        if (env("ANDROID_VERSION_CODE")) {
            versionCode envInt("ANDROID_VERSION_CODE")
            versionName env("ANDROID_VERSION_NAME")
        } else {
            // fallback
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we've used `ProcessBuilder` to start the `git` command and redirect its output to the input stream of the process. We then read the output from the input stream and parse it using parseInt with a radix of 10. Finally, we return the version code, or 0 if an exception occurs.

**Build.gradle**

```
def versionCode = {
    try {
        def process = new ProcessBuilder('git', 'rev-list', '--all', '--count')
                .redirectErrorStream(true)
                .start()
        def stdoutString = process.inputStream.text
        def revisions = Integer.parseInt(stdoutString.trim(), 10)
        return revisions
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return 0
    }
}

android {

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode versionCode()
        ...
    }
  ...
}
```

Note: Use `ProcessBuilder` instead of `exec` method: The `ProcessBuilder` class provides a more flexible and powerful way to execute commands than the `exec` method. By using `ProcessBuilder`, we can set the working directory, environment variables, and other options for the command.